# Add to Cart button not working in one div but works well everywhere else - Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to have a **potw** section on my home page. It only showcases 1 product from a collection and there's an Add to Cart button next to it that should add it to the cart but it isn't doing anything currently and I can't figure out why. I am using **Timber** and I have the exact same syntax on as I do on the *product.liquid* template.

Comment: you can change `button` for `input` to submit  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell it the id of the product/ variant you are trying to add.
Try adding this somewhere within the `<form>` element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}">
```